# Drawing a continuous error band in python using plt.fill_between()

Tags: pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, numpy-ndarray

I want to been trying to draw a continuous error band around the graph below but I am not getting the expected outcome. Here is what I did:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline 
x_mean=x_deterministic.mean()
x_std =x_deterministic.std()
x_deterministic=((d_result['M'][0]-d_result['M'][:])/d_result['M'][0])
plt.plot(d_trajectory['time'],x_deterministic, 'k')
plt.fill_between(d_trajectory['time'],x_mean-2*x_std,x_mean+2*x_std,color='b',alpha=.1)
```

Here is the graphical output I got:

[image]

Comment: `x_mean` and `x_std` are both constant so your `fill_between` region has constant upper and lower bands. You could replace `x_mean` with `x_deterministic` in your `fill_between` call, but I am not sure what that value would actually give you. You'd be stating that your uncertainty in time is constant, and that negative values are possible, which may or may not be true.

Comment: Hi @ ramzeek. Sorry for the late response. It worked, thank you. It actually gave me what I expected however, I still doubt the accuracy to an extent.